# else to run 5 times, after 5 times throw error

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ecmascript-6, try-catch

I have the following code where I search for a dynamic checkbox via it's id value... all mostly works fine, *however*, I do not want to bog down with a perceptual spin and endless re-checking with my `else`, how can I limit the below to running the else (re checking the function) to a `maximum of 5 times`? ... perhaps the question is more of a `try catch re catch` semantically?

I found a close solution in Java here on SO but not in JavaScript.

After the 5th time of checking a console error should be thrown, I want to check up to 5 times to handle load time inconsistency.

```
            let txt= document.querySelector('input[id^="txt"]');
            if (txt) {
                console.log("success");
                setTimeout(go__, 2000);
            } else { 
                console.log("try again");
                setTimeout(currentFunction, 22);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy just add a counter and ++ it in every else

```js
 let txt= document.querySelector('input[id^="txt"]');
 let counter = 0;
            if (txt) {
                console.log("success");
                setTimeout(go__, 2000);
            } else if(counter < 5){ 
                console.log("try again");
                setTimeout(currentFunction, 22);
                counter++;
            }
```

Then you can reset your counter whenever you want

Comment: Thank you. Semantically, would a try catch re-catch be more appropriate here?

Comment: Maybe, I just love using such simple things to resolve difficult problems , simple is always the best ;)